# Domain not found issue coming

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

After successful authentication in google api. i am getting error as 'Domain not found'. not getting how to assign domain for the request. here is my code

gapi.load("client:auth2", function () {

```
         gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'client id' });



    });

    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        // When signin status changes, this function is called.
        // If the signin status is changed to signedIn, we make an API call.
        if (isSignedIn) {
            loadClient()
            execute();
            clearInterval(s);
        }
    }

    function authenticate() {
        return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
            .signIn({ scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" }) // ux_mode: "redirect", prompt: "none"
            .then(function () { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
                function (err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });



    }
    function loadClient() {
        return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/admin/directory_v1/rest")
            .then(function () { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
                function (err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
    }
    // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
    function execute() {
        console.log(gapi.client.directory.users.list());

    }
```